# Set Ant property based on a regular expression in a file

Tags: regex, ant

I have the following in a file

```
version: [0,1,0]
```

and I would like to set an Ant property to the string value `0.1.0`.

The regular expression is

```
version:[[:space:]]\[([[:digit:]]),([[:digit:]]),([[:digit:]])\]
```

and I need to then set the property to

```
\1.\2.\3
```

to get

```
0.1.0
```

I can't workout how to use the Ant tasks together to do this.

I have Ant-contrib so can use those tasks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved it with this:

```
<loadfile property="burning-boots-js-lib-build.lib-version" srcfile="burning-boots.js"/>
<propertyregex property="burning-boots-js-lib-build.lib-version"
    override="true"
    input="${burning-boots-js-lib-build.lib-version}"
    regexp="version:[ \t]\[([0-9]),([0-9]),([0-9])\]"
    select="\1.\2.\3" />
```

But it seems a little wasteful - it loads the whole file into a property!

If anyone has any better suggestions please post :)

Comment: Thanks, FailedDev - Almost getting the hang of Ant now!

Answer (score 5):

Based on matt's second solution, this worked for me for any (text) file, one line or not. It has no apache-contrib dependencies.

```
<loadfile property="version" srcfile="version.txt">
  <filterchain>
    <linecontainsregexp>
      <regexp pattern="version:[ \t]\[([0-9]),([0-9]),([0-9])\]"/>
    </linecontainsregexp>
    <replaceregex pattern="version:[ \t]\[([0-9]),([0-9]),([0-9])\]" replace="\1.\2.\3" />
  </filterchain>
</loadfile>
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way that doesn't use ant-contrib, using [`loadproperties`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/loadproperties.html) and a [`filterchain`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html) (note that [`replaceregex`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html#replaceregex) is a "string filter" - see the [`tokenfilter`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html#tokenfilter) docs - and not the [`replaceregexp` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replaceregexp.html)):

```
<loadproperties srcFile="version.txt">
  <filterchain>
    <replaceregex pattern="\[([0-9]),([0-9]),([0-9])\]" replace="\1.\2.\3" />
  </filterchain>
</loadproperties>
```

Note the regex is a bit different, we're treating the file as a property file.

Alternatively you could use [`loadfile`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/loadfile.html) with a `filterchain`, for instance if the file you wanted to load from wasn't in properties format.

For example, if the file contents were just `[0,1,0]` and you wanted to set the `version` property to `0.1.0`, you could do something like:

```
<loadfile srcFile="version.txt" property="version">
  <filterchain>
    <replaceregex pattern="\s+\[([0-9]),([0-9]),([0-9])\]" replace="\1.\2.\3" />
  </filterchain>
</loadfile>
```